# Calculating the derivates of the output with respect to input for a give time step in LSTM tensorflow2.0

Tags: python, tensorflow, lstm, gradient-descent

I wrote a sample code to generate the real problem I am facing in my project. I am using an LSTM in tensorflow to model some time series data. Input dimensions are `(10, 100, 1)`, that is, 10 instances, 100 time steps, and number of features is 1. The output is of the same shape.

What I want to achieve after training the model is to study the influence of each of the inputs to each output at each particular time step. In other words, I would like to see which input variables affect my output the most (or which input has the most influence on the output/maybe large gradient) at each time step. Here is the code for this problem:

```
tf.keras.backend.clear_session()
tf.random.set_seed(42)

model_input = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(np.random.normal(size=(10, 100, 1)))
model_input = model_input.batch(10)
model_output = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(np.random.normal(size=(10, 100, 1)))
model_output = model_output.batch(10)

my_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.zip((model_input, model_output))

m_inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape=(None, 1))

lstm_outputs = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(32, return_sequences=True)(m_inputs)
m_outputs = tf.keras.layers.TimeDistributed(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1))(lstm_outputs)

my_model = tf.keras.Model(m_inputs, m_outputs, name="my_model")

my_optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001)
my_loss_fn = tf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredError()

my_epochs = 3

for epoch in range(my_epochs):

    for step, (x_batch_tr, y_batch_tr) in enumerate(my_dataset):
        x += 1
        # open a gradient tape to record the operations run during the forward pass, which enables autodifferentiation
        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:

            # Run the forward pass of the layer
            logits = my_model(x_batch_tr, training=True)

            # compute the loss value for this mismatch
            loss_value = my_loss_fn(y_batch_tr, logits)

        # use the gradient tape to automatically retrieve the gradients of the trainable variables with respect to the loss.
        grads = tape.gradient(loss_value, my_model.trainable_weights)

        # Run one step of gradient descent by updating the value of the variables to minimize the loss.
        my_optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, my_model.trainable_weights))

        print(f"Step {step}, loss: {loss_value}")


print("\n\nCalculate gradient of ouptuts w.r.t inputs\n\n")

for step, (x_batch_tr, y_batch_tr) in enumerate(my_dataset):
    # open a gradient tape to record the operations run during the forward pass, which enables autodifferentiation
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:

        tape.watch(x_batch_tr)

        # Run the forward pass of the layer
        logits = my_model(x_batch_tr, training=True)
        #tape.watch(logits[:, 10, :])   # this didn't help
        # compute the loss value for this mismatch
        loss_value = my_loss_fn(y_batch_tr, logits)

    # use the gradient tape to automatically retrieve the gradients of the trainable variables with respect to the loss.
#     grads = tape.gradient(logits, x_batch_tr)   # This works
#     print(grads.numpy().shape)                  # This works
    grads = tape.gradient(logits[:, 10, :], x_batch_tr)
    print(grads)
```

In other words, I would like to pay attention to the inputs that affect my output the most (at each particular time step).

To me `grads = tape.gradient(logits, x_batch_tr)` won't do the job cuz this will add the gradients from all outputs w.r.t each inputs.

However, the gradients are always None.

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`tf.GradientTape.batch_jacobian`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/GradientTape#batch_jacobian) to get precisely that information:

```py
grads = tape.batch_jacobian(logits, x_batch_tr)
print(grads.shape)
# (10, 100, 1, 100, 1)
```

Here, `grads[i, t1, f1, t2, f2]` gives you, for the example `i`, the gradient of output feature `f1` at time `t1` with respect to input feature `f2` at time `t2`. If, as in your case, you only have one feature, you can just say that `grads[i, t1, 0, t2, 0]` gives you the gradient of `t1` with respect to `t2`. Conveniently, you can also aggregate different axes or slices of this result to get aggregated gradients. For example, `tf.reduce_sum(grads[:, :, :, :10], axis=3)` would give you the gradient of each output time step with respect to the first ten input time steps.

About getting `None` gradients in your example, I think it is because you are doing the slicing operation outside of the gradient tape context, so the gradient tracking is lost.

Comment: Fixed the interpretation of the order of axes in `grads`. After the initial batch dimension, the first axes correspond to the output shape and the final axes to the input shape.

Comment: Thank you @jdehesa for the nice and complete answer I am looking for. However, one problem arises with calling batch_jacobian is the huge returned tensor that almost froze my computer to having full RAM. Any ideas? Thank you

Comment: @I.A Not many, I'm afraid, the computation is just rather expensive. But you may be able to reduce memory usage in exchange for some more execution time, try playing with the `parallel_iterations` parameter or passing `experimental_use_pfor=False` (I think this requires you to pass `persistent=True` to your gradient tape in eager mode).

Answer (score 0):

so the solution was to create a temporary tensor for part of the logits that we need to use in `tape.grad`, and register that tensor on tape using `tape.watch`

This is how it should be done:

```
for step, (x_batch_tr, y_batch_tr) in enumerate(my_dataset):
    # open a gradient tape to record the operations run during the forward pass, which enables autodifferentiation
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:

        tape.watch(x_batch_tr)

        # Run the forward pass of the layer
        logits = my_model(x_batch_tr, training=True)
        tensor_logits = tf.constant(logits[:, 10, :])
        tape.watch(tensor_logits)   # this didn't help

        # compute the loss value for this mismatch
        loss_value = my_loss_fn(y_batch_tr, logits)

    # use the gradient tape to automatically retrieve the gradients of the trainable variables with respect to the loss.
    grads = tape.gradient(tensor_logits, x_batch_tr)
    print(grads.numpy())
```